# Passing data from a Fragment to another one

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I known, that this question is already exist in this site and others, but I still try find a solution, because so far every solution is failed.

I have an Activity, which has 2 Fragments. In the first Fragment I have 5 EditText, and this inputs I need to pass to the second Fragment, but... I also have a Java Class in this Package, which has to work with this inputs's value, and that result I have to display in the second Fragment.
This is a average calculator.

This is my first Fragment:

```
package com.example.afotel;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class gyorsSzam extends Fragment {

    EditText gradeFive, gradeFour, gradeThree, gradeTwo, gradeOne;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gyors_szam, container, false);
        Button calculate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.gGyors);

        gradeFive = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numberOfGardeFive);
        gradeFour = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numberOfGardeFour);
        gradeThree = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numberOfGardeThree);
        gradeTwo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numberOfGardeTwo);
        gradeOne = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numberOfGardeOne);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fr.replace(R.id.gyorsSzamlalas, new jegyekFelLe());
                fr.commit();

                String gradeFiveSt = gradeFive.getText().toString();
                String gradeFourSt = gradeFour.getText().toString();
                String gradeThreeSt = gradeThree.getText().toString();
                String gradeTwoSt = gradeTwo.getText().toString();
                String gradeOneeSt = gradeOne.getText().toString();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Five", gradeFiveSt );
                bundle.putString("Four", gradeFourSt );
                bundle.putString("Three", gradeThreeSt );
                bundle.putString("Two", gradeTwoSt );
                bundle.putString("Ones", gradeOneeSt );

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

And this is my second Fragment:

```
package com.example.afotel;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class jegyekFelLe extends Fragment {


    public jegyekFelLe() {


    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jegyek_fel_le, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        String gradeFive = bundle.getString("Five");
        String gradeFour = bundle.getString("Four");
        String gradeThree  = bundle.getString("Three");
        String gradeTwo = bundle.getString("Two");
        String gradeOne = bundle.getString("One");

        TextView upFive = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.upFive);
        upFive.setText(gradeFive);

        TextView felNegyes = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.);
        upFour.setText(gradeFour);

        TextView upThree= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.upThree);
        upThree.setText(gradeThree);

        TextView upTwo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.upTwo);
        upTwo.setText(gradeTwo);

        TextView downOne = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dowbOne);
        leEgyes.setText(gradeOne);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

If the code contains the TextView upFive...(etc.) part, the program is crash if i click the calculate button. I don't know what is the problem, because i do everything that this video is say: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4i5Jk5RnFA

I know, that the Java Class in this example is not used, that's because I have this problem with the code. First I want to know how to pass data between two Fragments, and after I write to calculate the result that I need from this 5 EditText. 
Im a starter in Android Studio, so i need easy, undarstandable solution.

I hope You can understand my problem, sorry for my english.

Comment: You are not using the Bundle at all in your `gyorsSzam` fragment

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the bundle and add arguments to the fragment before committing transaction. You may have to change your code to this structure:

```
    Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
    //add items to the bundle then begin transacting
    Fragment jegyekFelLe= new jegyekFelLe();
    jegyekFelLe.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fr.replace(R.id.gyorsSzamlalas,jegyekFelLe );
    fr.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a model class, example is as follow

package com.example.afotel;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class gyorsSzam extends Fragment {

    EditText gradeFive, gradeFour, gradeThree, gradeTwo, gradeOne;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gyors_szam, container, false);
        Button calculate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.gGyors);

        gradeFive = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numberOfGardeFive);
        gradeFour = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numberOfGardeFour);
        gradeThree = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numberOfGardeThree);
        gradeTwo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numberOfGardeTwo);
        gradeOne = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numberOfGardeOne);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String gradeFiveSt = gradeFive.getText().toString();
                String gradeFourSt = gradeFour.getText().toString();
                String gradeThreeSt = gradeThree.getText().toString();
                String gradeTwoSt = gradeTwo.getText().toString();
                String gradeOneeSt = gradeOne.getText().toString();

                ModelClass modelClass = new ModelClass();
                modelClass.setFive(gradeFiveSt );
                modelClass.setFour(gradeFourSt );
                modelClass.setThree( gradeThreeSt );
                modelClass.setTwo(gradeTwoSt );
                modelClass.setOnes(gradeOneeSt );

                FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fr.replace(R.id.gyorsSzamlalas, new jegyekFelLe(modelClass));
                fr.commit();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}


package com.example.afotel;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class jegyekFelLe extends Fragment {
ModelClass modelClass;

    public jegyekFelLe(ModelClass modelClass) {

    this.modelClass = modelClass;

    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jegyek_fel_le, container, false);

        //Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        //String gradeFive = bundle.getString("Five");
        //String gradeFour = bundle.getString("Four");
        //String gradeThree  = bundle.getString("Three");
        //String gradeTwo = bundle.getString("Two");
        //String gradeOne = bundle.getString("One");

        TextView upFive = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.upFive);
        upFive.setText(modelClass.getFive());

        TextView felNegyes = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.);
        upFour.setText(modelClass.getFour());

        TextView upThree= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.upThree);
        upThree.setText(modelClass.getThree());

        TextView upTwo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.upTwo);
        upTwo.setText(modelClass.getTwo());

        TextView downOne = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dowbOne);
        leEgyes.setText(modelClass.getOnes());

        return rootView;
    }
}


public class ModelClass {
    private String Ones;
    private String Two;
    private String Three;
    private String Four;
    private String Five;
    public String getOnes() {
        return Ones;
    }
    public void setOnes(String ones) {
        Ones = ones;
    }
    public String getTwo() {
        return Two;
    }
    public void setTwo(String two) {
        Two = two;
    }
    public String getThree() {
        return Three;
    }
    public void setThree(String three) {
        Three = three;
    }
    public String getFour() {
        return Four;
    }
    public void setFour(String four) {
        Four = four;
    }
    public String getFive() {
        return Five;
    }
    public void setFive(String five) {
        Five = five;
    }



}
```

Comment: you can also use your code just put fragment calling after creating bundle

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing your bundle as a arguments in fragment

*sending data from fragment A to B

```
 Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("Your_key",data)
   //add items to the bundle then begin transacting
    Fragment fragment= new jegyekFelLe();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fr.replace(R.id.gyorsSzamlalas,fragment );
    fr.commit();
```

*get the data from fragment a

```
String data = getArguments.getString("Your_key")
```

Comment: Thanks your help, now I understand!

Answer (score 0):

1.) you need to use the Activity's support fragment manager, and not the Fragment's child fragment manager

2.) you need to give the Bundle to the Fragment as an `arguments` bundle before it is added to the fragment manager in the transaction.

```
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String gradeFiveSt = gradeFive.getText().toString();
            String gradeFourSt = gradeFour.getText().toString();
            String gradeThreeSt = gradeThree.getText().toString();
            String gradeTwoSt = gradeTwo.getText().toString();
            String gradeOneeSt = gradeOne.getText().toString();

            FragmentTransaction fr = (((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()).beginTransaction();

            Fragment fragment = new jegyekFelLe();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Five", gradeFiveSt );
            bundle.putString("Four", gradeFourSt );
            bundle.putString("Three", gradeThreeSt );
            bundle.putString("Two", gradeTwoSt );
            bundle.putString("Ones", gradeOneeSt );
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fr.replace(R.id.gyorsSzamlalas, fragment);
            fr.commit();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, its help!