# Call a Java Class method to work with the EditTexts's values

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My problem with the EditTexts's values is solved ([Passing data from a Fragment to another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54722733/passing-data-from-a-fragment-to-another-one)), so now finally I can move on to work with these values. But who else except that I have another problem? I don't, but I have some.

So, my goal is to get 5 values from the user, and with this values I want to work (calculate the average).

As I mentioned in the previous topic, I have a Java Class, which has a lot of methods. One of these methods is the grade calculator.

Part of my Average Java Class:

```
package com.example.afotel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Average {

        double numberOfGradeOne, numberOfGradeTwo, numberOfGradeThree, numberOfGradeFour, numberOfGradeFive;
        private double numberOfGrades, gradeSum, gradeAverage;

         void calculateAverage (double numberOfGradeFive, double numberOfGradeFour, double numberOfGradeThree, double numberOfGradeTwo, double numberOfGradeOne) {
            numberOfGrades=numberOfGradeFive+numberOfGradeFour+numberOfGradeThree+numberOfGradeTwo+numberOfGradeOne;
            gardeSum=5*numberOfGradeFive+4*numberOfGradeFour+3*numberOfGradeThree+2*numberOfGradeTwo+numberOfGradeOne;
            gradeAverage=gradeSum/numberOfGrades;
        }

public double getAverage () {
    return gradeAverage;
    }
```

In my second Fragment (jegyekFelLe (sry its not english)) I want to call the Java Class's grade calculator method.

```
    package com.example.afotel;


    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class jegyekFelLe extends Fragment {


        public jegyekFelLe() {
        }
          @Nullable
            @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jegyek_fel_le, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    String gradeFive = bundle.getString("Five");
    String gradeFour = bundle.getString("Four");
    String gradeThree  = bundle.getString("Three");
    String gradeTwo = bundle.getString("Two");
    String gradeOne = bundle.getString("One");

            Average average = new Average();
            double five, four, three, two, one;

            five=Double.valueOf(gradeFive);
            four=Double.valueOf(gradeFour);
            three=Double.valueOf(gradeThree);
            two=Double.valueOf(gradeTwo);
            one=Double.valueOf(gradeOne);

            averaga.calculateAverage (five,four, three, two, one);
            double averageH=0;
            averageH=average.getAverage();
            gradeFive = String.valueOf(averageH);

            TextView averageText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.average_id);
            averageText.setText(gradeFive);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I thought, that if I call the calculateAverage method first, than the getter I can reach the result, but it's not working. I expected for this. 
What is the solution? I'm helpless with this. What or/and how I should resolve the problem, to work with the 5 inputs with the calculateAverage and than get the final value to show in the second Fragment?

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "but it's not working"? Please provide the actual result, with logcat if necessary.

Comment: Besides the typo of "gardeSum" vs "gradeSum", and "averaga" vs "average".

Comment: In my Android Studio my variables's name is on another language, this code is just an example, where I rename my variables. Yes, there is a lot of typo, but the gardeSum and the gradeSum is the same variable, so like the averaga and average, I just messed up with the names, sorry for that.

Comment: By "it's not working" I mean, that the program is build succesfully, but when I want to try it, it's crashed.

Comment: "it's crashed", then it is necessary for you to post the logcat.

Comment: I tested one more time, and now I realised, that the problem was that I never give every EditText a value, but it's reguired. Basically I solved my problem, it was my mistake, sorry for that.

Comment: Sound like this question is generated earlier than the code shown. But since it is solved, that is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a `static method` then invoke by calling `Average.calculate(gradeOne, gradeTwo, gradeThree, gradeFour, gradeFive)` .
And the `class` should look like this.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.OptionalDouble;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class Average {

public static double calculate(double... inputs) {

    AtomicReference<Double> multiplier = new AtomicReference<>((double) 0);

    OptionalDouble average = Arrays.stream(inputs)
            .map(value -> {
                multiplier.set((multiplier.get() + 1));
                return value * multiplier.get();
            })
            .average();

    return average.isPresent() ? average.getAsDouble() : 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Wanted to downvote: the way author calculate average has no problem, though there is a little unnecessary complex.

Comment: Sorry but I am also curious. Can you please write a solution?

Comment: I am waiting for the author to provide more information on the question necessary for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class Average {

    double numberOfGradeOne, numberOfGradeTwo, numberOfGradeThree, numberOfGradeFour, numberOfGradeFive;
     double numberOfGrades, gradeSum, gradeAverage;

    public Average(double numberOfGradeOne, double numberOfGradeTwo, double numberOfGradeThree, double numberOfGradeFour, double numberOfGradeFive, double numberOfGrades) {
        this.numberOfGradeOne = numberOfGradeOne;
        this.numberOfGradeTwo = numberOfGradeTwo;
        this.numberOfGradeThree = numberOfGradeThree;
        this.numberOfGradeFour = numberOfGradeFour;
        this.numberOfGradeFive = numberOfGradeFive;
        this.numberOfGrades = numberOfGrades;
        calculateAverage();
    }

    void calculateAverage () {
        numberOfGrades=numberOfGradeFive+numberOfGradeFour+numberOfGradeThree+numberOfGradeTwo+numberOfGradeOne;
        gradeSum =5*numberOfGradeFive+4*numberOfGradeFour+3*numberOfGradeThree+2*numberOfGradeTwo+numberOfGradeOne;
        gradeAverage=gradeSum/numberOfGrades;
    }

    public double getGradeAverage() {
        return gradeAverage;
    }
}
```

In your Fragment :

```
average = new Average(12,34,54,12,44.6,5);
        Log.v("Average",""+average.getGradeAverage());
        textView.setText(average.getGradeAverage()+" ");
```

Or you can even comment calculateAverage(); from Constructor and call like this :

```
average = new Average(12,34,54,12,44.6,5);
        average.calculateAverage();
        Log.v("Average",""+average.getGradeAverage());
        textView.setText(average.getGradeAverage()+" ");
```